# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los elementos de una consulta en python?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

Estoy desarrollando un proceso en Python, pero necesito consultar unos RFC's de una tabla y de ahí, hacer comparaciones, mi pregunta es, después de que ejecuta la consulta y me devuelve los elementos, ¿Cómo puedo iterar uno por uno para hacer dicha comparación?

```
import MySQLdb

# Datos de conexión 
db = MySQLdb.connect(host = "myHost", user = "myUser", passwd = "myPass", db = "myDB")

# Creación de cursor 
c = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

# Ejecución de consulta en MySQL
c.execute("SELECT rfc FROM accesossat")

# Recuperación de datos de la consulta 
result_set = c.fetchall()

# Impresión de datos de la consulta
for row in result_set:
    print(row['rfc'])
```

Comment: usa un while en vez del for

Comment: Cambia print(row['rfc']) por **print(row[0])**. Si necesitas usar ese dato puedes hacer **dato=row[0]** y a partir de esto hacer las comparaciones que necesites